# How to add automatically bootstrap 4 order-lg-1 and order-lg-2 classes for columns in foreach loop based on the count?

Tags: posts, customization, loop, twitter-bootstrap

How to add automatically bootstrap 4 `order-lg-1 and order-lg-2` classes for columns in foreach loop based on the count?

**PHP and Html Code**

```
<?php
    //get your custom posts ids as an array
    $howtoplaycontent_args = get_posts(array(
            'post_type'   => 'howtoplaycontent',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'fields' => 'ids'
        )
    );
    //loop over each post
    foreach($howtoplaycontent_args as $p){
        //get the meta you need form each post
        $howtoplaycontent = get_post_meta($p, 'howtoplaycontent', true );
    }

?>

 <?php
 $count = 0;
 foreach ($howtoplaycontent as $hpc)
 {
 $count ++;

 if($count == 1) {?>
 
 <div class="row courses_row" style="background-color: #f8f8f8">
 
   <div class="container">
        <div class="row" style="padding: 15px;">
          <div class="col-lg-6 course_col order-lg-1">
          </div>
          
          <div class="col-lg-6 course_col order-lg-2">
          </div>
          
          
        </div>
 
 </div>
 
 
 <?php } ?>
 
 <?php if($count == 2) {?>
 
 <div class="row courses_row" style="background-color: #f8f8f8">
 
   <div class="container">
        <div class="row" style="padding: 15px;">
          <div class="col-lg-6 course_col order-lg-2">
          </div>
          
          <div class="col-lg-6 course_col order-lg-1">
          </div>
          
          
        </div>
 
 </div>
 
 
 <?php } ?>
```

**Example Design**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should use the PHP [modulo operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) for that. Since you need two different layouts, you should calculate your classes numbers according to `$count % 2` and `($count + 1) % 2`:

```php
<?php
$count = 0;
foreach ($howtoplaycontent as $hpc): ?>
<div class="row courses_row" style="background-color: #f8f8f8">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row" style="padding: 15px;">
            <div class="col-lg-6 course_col order-lg-<?php echo $count % 2 + 1; ?>">
            </div>
          
            <div class="col-lg-6 course_col order-lg-<?php echo ($count + 1) % 2 + 1; ?>">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php $count ++;
endforeach; ?>
```

**Update**

Since you need a different background color on even and odd rows, I suggest you to define two additional classes in your CSS:

```css
.row.courses_row.odd_row {
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
}
.row.courses_row.even_row {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

and then use the following code:

```php
<?php
$count = 0;
foreach ($howtoplaycontent as $hpc): ?>
<div class="row courses_row <?php echo $count % 2 ? 'even' : 'odd'; ?>_row">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row" style="padding: 15px;">
            <div class="col-lg-6 course_col order-lg-<?php echo $count % 2 + 1; ?>">
            </div>
          
            <div class="col-lg-6 course_col order-lg-<?php echo ($count + 1) % 2 + 1; ?>">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php $count ++;
endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: thanks it is working now

Comment: what about `<div class="row courses_row" style="background-color: #f8f8f8">` row background color after each row?

Comment: @FarhanDharsi What's wrong with that line? Background needs to be different on even and odd rows? You didn't show it in your question example design, you had that line in both `if ($count == 1) { ... }` and `if ($count == 1) { ... }` blocks. Explain what do you want and I will update my answer.

Comment: background need to be different on odd rows?

Comment: @FarhanDharsi Updated the answer. If it would work for you, please [mark the answer as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/tour#:~:text=The%20person%20who%20asked%20can%20mark%20one%20answer%20as%20%22accepted%22.).

Comment: eveny row is `odd_row` even_row is not working or showing ?

Comment: working with this `<?php echo ($count % 2 == 1) ? 'even' : 'odd'; ?>_row"` code

Comment: @FarhanDharsi My typo, typed `$counter` instead of `$count`, fixed it now. `<?php echo $count % 2 ? 'even' : 'odd'; ?>` would work too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110158/discussion-between-farhan-dharsi-and-ivan-shatsky).